# Issues with 2d array built from .txt file

Tags: java

I've been able to create an array using a .txt file. However, right now when printing the array, it reprints the final row repeatedly instead of the ones that came before. I believe that I assigned the correct values and made sure to assign them to the array.

I've tried looping through and assigning each index with correct value, and then going down each row until they are all assigned. This results in the final overriding everything however.

```java
private double[][] Grid;

public GridMonitor(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner FileName = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
    int totalRow = 0;
    while (FileName.hasNextLine())
    {
        String[] string = FileName.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
        totalRow++;
        Grid = new double[totalRow][string.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < totalRow; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < string.length; j++)
            {
                Grid[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(string[j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(Grid));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(Grid));
    FileName.close();
}
```

It should show result something similar to

> [3.0][3.0], [2.0][10.0][7.0], [5.0][6.0][9.0], [4.0][5.0][8.0]

but instead shows

> [4.0][5.0][8.0], [4.0][5.0][8.0], [4.0][5.0][8.0], [4.0][5.0][8.0]

Comment: I would be careful naming an array of strings as "`string`". I'd go for "`strings`" or "`stringArray`". Maybe even in this case something like "`rowContents`" or just "`row`".

Comment: @arcadeblast77 alrighty, makes sense. Any idea about the issue at hand though, as this change didn't address it.

Comment: Not sure from a glance, though sometimes improving readability (making the code read like proper English) can make bugs like this easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss that array has row and column like this: `double[][] grid = new double[row][col]`, so when you read the file line by line you cannot find out the number of rows before you get the final line.

```
public static double[][] readGridFromFile(Path file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    final Pattern space = Pattern.compile("\\s+");

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.toFile())))) {
        List<double[]> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            lines.add(Arrays.stream(space.split(scan.nextLine().trim()))
                            .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                            .toArray());
        }

        double[][] grid = new double[lines.size()][];
        int row = 0;

        for (double[] line : lines)
            grid[row++] = line;

        return grid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did initialized the grid. the problem aparently, was that I reasigned it every time, so it overwrote the previous iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are repeatedly assigning a new array to Grid with `Grid = new double[totalRow][string.length];` thereby overwriting the old value.

Comment: Thank you, I see the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the nested for loop, Grid is being populated by the same row everytime. Remove the outer loop and initialise a row counter to 0 and increment it inside the outer while loop.

```
int rc = 0;
while ( Filename.hasNextLine()){
// Code before Nested For loop
for(j=0;j<string.length;j++){
Grid[rc][j] = // your code
}
rc++;
}
```